# How to read all values in an array returned by a PHP file using AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

I am using AJAX to fetch a multidimensional array, so a multidimensional array is returned to AJAX, how can I deal with the data with AJAX? I need to read all values in the multidimensional array. I use the following code to return the array to AJAX.

```
$resultset=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $resultset[]=$row;
}
print_r($resultset);
```

How to read all values in an array returned by a PHP file using AJAX?

Answer (score 3):

While it is possible to parse the output of print_r in JavaScript, it would be rather silly to do so when robust libraries for other data formats already exist for both languages.

Use [JSON](http://json.org/) (links at the bottom of the page will take you to libraries for generating it in PHP and reading it in JavaScript).

Comment: jQuery has a nice built-in function that looks like this: `$.getJSON(url, data, callback)`. Details and example at api.jquery.com.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) to transfer data across multiple platforms. If your data looks like:

```
<?php
  $a = array( );
  $a[ "foo" ] = array( );
  $a[ "bar" ] = array( );
  $a[ "foo" ][ "foo-1" ] = 1;
  $a[ "foo" ][ "foo-2" ] = 2;
  $a[ "foo" ][ "foo-3" ] = 3;
  $a[ "foo" ][ "foo-4" ] = array( "yada", "yada" );
  $a[ "bar" ][ "bar-1" ] = 1;
  $a[ "bar" ][ "bar-2" ] = 2;
  $a[ "bar" ][ "bar-3" ] = 3;
  $a[ "bar" ][ "bar-4" ] = array( "blah", "blah" );
?>
```

Then its json_encode( $a ) will return:

```
{"foo":{"foo-1":1,"foo-2":2,"foo-3":3,"foo-4":["yada","yada"]},"bar":{"bar-1":1,"bar-2":2,"bar-3":3,"bar-4":["blah","blah"]}}
```

You can use the JavaScript's eval function to convert this string into an object and the iterate it just like you would iterate a php array.

Comment: +1 for showing how JSON looks. As David Dorward noted, www.json.org is a good resource and explains the structure in more detail.

Comment: If anyone knows what (), [] and {} mean in JavaScript, learning JSON should be a piece of cake!

Answer (score 1):

PHP

```
echo json_encode($resultset);
```

JS:

```
var array = json_decode(input);
```

json_decode in javascript is not supported by default, you might use a framework to implement this functionality. E.g: in prototype:

```
var array = input.evalJSON();
```

Comment: it would be most helpful if downvotes were commented. now I don't know which part of the answer is regarded as wrong by someone.

Comment: Steven: it's prototype in my example, but your choice depends on your needs. jQuery is very popular nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use JSON for that. E.g. in php instead of print_r use json_encode($resultset). And in javascript use some JSON-supporting lib (jquery/mootools will do) to decode JSON. That is it.